# How to remove %23 sign at the end of the URL?

Tags: asp.net, url, urldecode, iirf

Google adsbot is encoding **# sign to %23**. Our sites include # sign at the end of the URL. Google automatically encoding it. can anyone help us on this. How to remove %23 at the end of the URL.

```
www.abcd.com/topics/onetwo.aspx# is encoding with     www.abcd.com/topics/onetwo.aspx%23
```

How to remove or redirect for this issue.

If we write **UrlDecoding Off** in IIRF file. It is working but in our sites we have special characters also. So, it is always UrlDecoding should be ON

Comment: you are entering the url directly or you are redirecting to that page?

Comment: @shreesha, Google adsbot automatically encoding # with %23 and trying to load it. this is not Humans mistake. it is automatic.